# Storybook how to support use --modern flag when building/compiling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, command-line-interface, storybook

I'm new to storybook. Recently I've found out that my storybook is not displaying in IE. I've found out that vue cli has the ability to support older browser by enabling the modern mode.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode

So my question is can I use the --modern flag when building storybook in order support older browsers?

***vue-cli-service storybook:serve -p 6006 -c config/storybook --modern***

Or is there a better solution to support storybook in IE?

Here is what appears in IE 11 console

[image]

Comment: Is it all versions of IE, or is there a specific version that it stops working at?

Comment: Were testing it in IE edge and IE 11 and both does not display anything